# Как прикрепить LEFT JOIN к запросу?

Tags: mysql

Приветствую всех. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прикрепить к этому запросу еще одно условие:

```
SELECT `cabinet`.`name_test`, `answers`.`answer_id`
FROM `cabinet` LEFT JOIN `answers` ON `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`
WHERE `user_id` = '184918649' AND `friend_id` = '353281'
```

Нужно прикрепить еще одно условие:
`user_id` = '353281'
Чтобы получить такую таблицу:

```
name_test______answer_id___answer_id2
Первый тест_______101_________111
Второй тест_______012_________212
```

Comment: Уточните что у вас выводит исходный запрос и в какой таблице у вас поле user_id.

Comment: user_id в таблице answers. Исходный запрос выводит таблицу выше, кроме поля answer_id2.

Comment: Почему то не смог ответить в последнем сообщение, поэтому отвечу здесь. Сделал так, работает.
SELECT 
  cabinet.name_test, 
  a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
  a2.answer_id as answer_id2
FROM cabinet
  JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
    AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
  LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
    AND a2.user_id = '353281'
GROUP BY answer_id

Answer (score 2):

`user_id` IN ('184918649','353281')

Comment: Первое условие:
`user_id` = '184918649' AND `friend_id` = '353281'
Второе условие:
`user_id` = '353281'
Для первого юзера нужно, чтобы совпадало user_id и friend_id. А для второго юзера только user_id.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял:

```
SELECT 
  cabinet.name_test, 
  a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
  a2.answer_id as answer_id2
FROM cabinet
  LEFT JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
    AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
  LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
    AND a2.user_id = '353281'
```

Comment: Не совсем. Он выводит в результирующую таблицу и третий тест тоже. А должен выводить только те тесты, где `user_id` =  '184918649'
AND  `friend_id` =  '353281'. Их у меня в таблице только два. Вот рабочий запрос:
SELECT `cabinet`.`name_test`, `answers`.`answer_id`, (
SELECT `answer_id` FROM `answers` WHERE `user_id` = '353281' AND `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`
) as answer_2 FROM `cabinet` INNER JOIN `answers`
 WHERE `user_id` = '184918649' AND `friend_id` = '353281' AND `answers`.`test_id` = `cabinet`.`test_id`

Comment: Только он выбирает answers.test_id = cabinet.test_id два раза для каждого пользователя. Как этого можно избежать и записать это условие только один раз для обоих пользователей?

Comment: для этого достаточно убрать первый left от join'а:

    SELECT 
      cabinet.name_test, 
      a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
      a2.answer_id as answer_id2
    FROM cabinet
      JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
        AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
      LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
        AND a2.user_id = '353281'

Ваш запрос с вложенным вернет декартово произведение тестов ``user_id = '184918649' AND friend_id = '353281'`` и ``user_id = '353281'``. Не делайте так.

Comment: Теперь он выводит в результирующую таблицу первый тест два раза. Вот таблица answers:
http://s017.radikal.ru/i420/1212/df/6a48e815e0ed.png
А вот результирующая таблица по вашему запросу:
http://i023.radikal.ru/1212/42/82265f578499.png
Как сделать, чтобы он два раза один и тот же тест не показывал? Всего должно быть 2 строки, так как условие a1.user_id =  '184918649'
AND a1.friend_id =  '353281' встречается только 2 раза. А он ищет дальше. Как поставить лимит, чтобы нашел один раз и больше не искал?

Comment: ну смотрите, у вас user=353281 проходил нулевой тест два раза. какой из ответов вы предлагаете не учитывать?

Comment: Учитываться должен только первый найденный, то бишь 7 строка. Мне нужно всего 2 строчки вывести, для первого и второго теста. Подозреваю, что нужно поставить Limit 1, но где именно?

Comment: С точки зрения базы нет понятия первая или вторая строка. Строки равнозначны, можно только варьировать минимальными/максимальными значениями, например:

    SELECT 
      cabinet.name_test, 
      a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
      MIN(a2.answer_id) as answer_id2
    FROM cabinet
      JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
        AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
      LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
        AND a2.user_id = '353281'
    GROUP BY cabinet.name_test, answer_id2

насколько это правильно - судить вам...