# Сортировка по минимальному значению.

Tags: mysql

С праздником всех. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не правильно делаю. Вот запрос:
`SELECT answer_id FROM answers WHERE friend_id = 353281 ORDER BY MIN(id)`
Выводит всегда одно и то же значение, даже если меняю MIN на MAX. Почему так?

Comment: Опишите задачу. Вы странно используете агрегатную функцию.

Comment: Я хочу отсортировать answer_id по минимальному полю id. Т.е., чтобы он гарантированно вывел самую первую запись, где friend_id = 353281. В случае с MAX он должен вывести самую последнюю запись.

Comment: `order by id asc` -сортировка по возрастанию. `order by id desc` -сортировка по убыванию.

Comment: Вот весь запрос:
    SELECT 
  cabinet.name_test,
  a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
  a2.answer_id as answer_id2
FROM cabinet
  JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
    AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
  LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
    AND a2.user_id = '353281'
GROUP BY answer_id ORDER BY a1.id
Я все правильно сделал? Т.е. теперь он будет гарантированно возвращать первую запись где user_id = 353281?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос: потому что `min(id)` -- константа, так что это всё равно, что `order by 0`. По поводу того, что делать, см. комментарий @KaZaца

Comment: А я разве не так сделал?

Answer (score 1):

Выводит одну и ту же запись, потому что у тебя однозначное условие WHERE (сравниваешь на ID, а он уникальный и он один, поэтому возвращает одну и ту же запись).

Если хочешь выбрать минимальное значение:

```
SELECT `answer_id` FROM `answers` ORDER BY `answer_id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

А если хочешь использовать агрегатную функцию min(), max(), то условие WHERE не нужно. Разберись с логикой запросов. Ты не до конца понимаешь что пишешь.

Answer (score 0):

@Dimaz, вы переписали с ошибкой тот запрос, который я вам писал (комментарий к ответу [на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177205/mysql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-left-join-%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83) - самый последний...). Попробуйте еще раз:

```
SELECT 
  cabinet.name_test, 
  a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
  MIN(a2.answer_id) as answer_id2
FROM cabinet
  JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
    AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
  LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
    AND a2.user_id = '353281'
GROUP BY cabinet.name_test, answer_id2
```

или скажите что в нем вас не устраивает.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я тебя понял, ты сортируешь только чтобы первую запись найти, может лучше так?
select min(answer_id) ... where ...